# Login page is not redirecting to home page even after entering the correct credential

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc, session, servlets

I have **MySessionListener.java** where I have overridden `sessionCreated()` & `sessionDestroyed()` method. When I am adding the following code in **web.xml** file

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>com.abhi.vnd.filters.MySessionListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

The login page is not redirecting to home page even after entering the correct credentials. I had added lines of code because I need to display the number of sessions.

I checked log files where the session is getting created but not able to reach home page it is showing login page again and again.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How is this JSF related, other than you using it?

Comment: Changed to jsp tag. Thanks @Kukeltje please help me out by answering the question if you are familiar with this question

Comment: I'm not familiar with spring, spring-mvc or spring-security or any other spring related things. So for me it is impossible to help. But for others it is to since the filter seems to be **your** code and you did not post any of it. Please create a [mcve] and improve. Otherwise you'll stand a chance it gets closed... Good luck